# fastapi and jinja load a html

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, fastapi

I am trying to create a simple home page with FastApi and Jinja2.

What i want to do is enter my home page that load a html without passing a response back but my html loads

This is my very simple code

"main.py"

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

template = Jinja2Templates(directory="./")
@app.get("/")
def home():
    return template.TemplateResponse('index.html',{request:""})
```

"index.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello FastApi and jinja2
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the `Request` is a must. Just add the `Request` to your dictionary on `TemplateResponse` and it will work.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

template = Jinja2Templates(directory="./")

@app.get("/")
def home(request: Request):
    return template.TemplateResponse('index.html',{"request": request})
```

Comment: I am using a background process to send emails. And in email, I am using JInja2Templates. So, how do I get `request` object to pass in TemplateResponse as I am not using fastapi route.